# joomla language flags order

Tags: joomla, flags

Joomla version 3.5.1.
Falang version 2.2.1

Currently have 3 langs displayed in folowing order: RU > ET > EN

Need to change display order to: ET > RU > EN

In Content Languages section **ordering is missing**.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't fix this issue from the Joomla backend either. However I found a workaround. If you have direct access to the MySQL database, go to the table jos_languages. The last field is named Ordering. Here you are able to change the ordering in any way you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found the solution yourselve.
If not I hope this will help you.

Go to your Joomla backend.
Then go to Extensions and select Language(s)
Select Content languages.

There you can edit the order of the languages.
Do that and view the result at your website.